# Create a unique ID for instances of class

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, but I have some experience with Java.  I am trying to create a program that lets a user create a task with a due date and description, which is then saved in a data structure until they complete it.

I want to add a unique identifier to each task when it is created and display it to the user, so they can use the identifier to look up the task later, (or at least I can use it to look up the task as the due dates and descriptions might not be unique).

My issue is, coming from Java, I want to create a "Task" class with the attributes I wish to save, as well as a unique identifier.

In Java, I would use a private static variable inside the class that would get increased each time a new instance of the class was created.  However, this does not seem to work in javascript, and other stack overflow posts recommend workarounds that do not seem to apply to my situation.

I saw another post here that recommended using the "const" keyword, but that seems to throw an error when I try to update it.

What is the javascript version of a private static int variable that can live inside of a class which I can increase with each new instance?

Comment: Question - does it need to live inside the class?

Comment: https://devland.at/a/private-methods-and-fields-in-javascript-classes, https://v8.dev/features/class-fields, etc, or just don't worry about it being exposed. Or use a variable local to the module, hence not visible outside the module (e.g., you're importing the class def to use elsewhere).

Comment: By the way, if you want a universally-unique identifier that can be generated across systems compatibly yet without coordinating, use a [Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have static properties, only [static methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). What I would do in your case is use a local variable declared outside the class. For example:

```js
let counter = 0;

class Task {
  constructor(name) {
    this.id = counter++;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

console.log(new Task("Test A"));
console.log(new Task("Test B"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just to better understand, I should have all my JS in one file as opposed to multiple files for different classes like how I would organize Java?  Very new, apologies.  Thanks again!

Comment: @smoonUW depends on what environment you're working with. On the backend, using nodeJS for example, you can seperate your code into modules, and import the modules where required.

Comment: Thanks you for your help!